# Передача результатов поиска GridView в контроллер yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть задача после нажатия на кнопку передать результаты поиска из GridView в контроллер. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?
Код генерировал через Gii.
GridView обернут в Pjax.

Answer (score 0):

автор, поправьте меня, если не прав.

GridView - виджет отрисовки данных, который берет данные с DataProvider, который в свою очередь по-хорошему должен вызыватся в контроллере.

С помощью виджета вы только отрисовываете данные.

С вариантов, как мне кажется

1) ajax-запрос обратно, и отлов через `Yii::$app->request->isAjax` -> такое себе

2) У вас DataProvider результат можно дорисовать самому до вывода во view,

`$query = News::find();    
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(    
    [   
        'query' => $query
    ]
);введите сюда код
# нужный нам кусочек
# например, должен полагать, вам нужно знать, сколько значений нашлось
$myData = $query->count();
   </pre>`

3) ещё как вариант, можно унаследовать сам GridView, и там уже(если реально специфичная логика) делать логирование